# How to toggle isBackgroundRestricted() as a user?

Tags: android, performance, battery

The [`isBackgroundRestricted()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#isBackgroundRestricted()) allows an app to check whether a user has enabled background restrictions for an app. As a user of the app, how/where can I change this setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is toggled via the "Battery" section of the app "info" page in settings:

Settings > Apps & notifications > [Choose App] > Advanced > Battery > Background restriction